# How to use the textbox data for data saving location of my datagridview data

Tags: visual-studio

Can someone help me with my problem?
I already have a program that saves my data in the location I declared in the program (D:\Data Save).
What I want now is I choose the location using the folder browser dialog that pastes the location in a textbox. This one I can browse already and paste the location in the text box. But the problem is when I change the (D:\Data Save) into my textbox the data is not saving.
I'm working on this for many days already. So I need help from the expert.

In my current program, I declare the D:\Data Save\ for the location, but I want to change it depending on the location I choose in my text label using the folder browser dialog.
Thank you in advance.

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("D:\Data Save\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_hhmmss") & "_Line" & Form1.LineTxt.Text + ".csv")
                Dim dgvColumnNames As List(Of String) = Form1.DataGridView1.Columns.
                        Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).ToList().
                        Select(Function(c) c.Name).ToList()

                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", dgvColumnNames))

                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Form1.DataGridView1.Rows

                    Dim rowData As New List(Of String)
                    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In Form1.DataGridView1.Columns
                        rowData.Add(Convert.ToString(row.Cells(column.Name).Value))
                    Next
                    sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", rowData))
                    sw.Close()
                Next

            End Using
```